# async method with completed event

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I use .net 4.0 and i've tried to figure out how to use async method to await DocumentCompleted event to complete and return the value. My original code is above, how can i turn it into async/await model in this scenario ?

```
private class BrowserWindow
    {
        private bool webBrowserReady = false;
        public string content = "";


        public void Navigate(string url)
        {

            xxx browser = new xxx();

            browser.DocumentCompleted += new EventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
            webBrowserReady = false;
            browser.CreateControl();
            if (browser.IsHandleCreated)
                browser.Navigate(url);


            while (!webBrowserReady)
            {
                //Application.DoEvents(); >> replace it with async/await 
            }

        }

        private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               ...

                  webBrowserReady = true;

                  content = browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }

        public delegate string AsyncMethodCaller(string url);
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

So we need a method that returns a task when the `DocumentCompleted` event fires.  Anytime you need that for a given event you can create a method like this:

```
public static Task WhenDocumentCompleted(this WebBrowser browser)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, args) => tcs.SetResult(true);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Once you have that you can use:

```
await browser.WhenDocumentCompleted();
```

Comment: thanks for your nice solution, but one problem is that i'm using vs 2010 and .net 4.0 so i must use the old style rather than await synctax (4.5). I'm a bit confused of how to get it to work in 4.0

Comment: @namvo You specifically said that you wanted a solution using async/await, so I assumed you were using the compatibility pack.  If you're not, then just use `ContinueWith` on the task that the method returns (the `WhenDocumentCompleted` event will work in 4.0) and put the code that should run after the document is completed inside of there.  You most likely want to use a lambda for convenience's sake.

Comment: This seems like an incredibly useful and essential bit of knowledge that turned out to be harder to find than I expected. Basically this is seems to be how you define aynsc tasks that don't simply consist of other async tasks. Is there a more prevalent place where one might learn about this while studying async programming? Are there other related pieces of knowledge that go along with this (other classes related to TaskCompletionSource that can provide tasks)? I figured out that I should also probably SetException appropriately, but wonder if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN There are lots of books on the subject, lots of tutorials online, lots of blogs, lots of questions on SO.  It's not hard at all to find information on the topic.

Comment: @Servy I guess I was just surprised it wasn't more visible in the Microsoft documentation on async tasks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) and other articles generally talking about async tasks. I see now that Googling "custom async task c#" gives much more relevant results than "async taks c#".

Answer (score 2):

@Servy had the genius answer I was looking for, but it didn't apply to my use case well.  I found errors when the event is raised multiple times due to the event handler trying to set the result on the `TaskCompletionSource` on subsequent event invocations.

I enhanced his answer in two ways.  The first is simply to unsubscribe the `DocumentCompleted` event once it has been handled the first time.

```cs
public static Task WhenDocumentCompleted(this WebBrowser browser)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompletedHandler;
    return tcs.Task;

    void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.DocumentCompleted -= DocumentCompletedHandler;
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

> Note I'm using a local function here to capture the `TaskCompletionSource` instance, which requires a minimum of C# 7.0.

The second enhancement is to add a timeout.  My particular use case was in unit tests, and I wanted to make waiting for my particular event deterministic and not wait indefinitely if there was a problem.

I chose to use a timer for this, and set it to fire only once, then stop the timer when it is no longer needed.  Alternatively could leverage a `CancellationToken` here to manage the `TaskCompletionSource` but I feel this requires maintainers to know more about their usage and timers are more universally understood.

```cs
public static Task WhenDocumentCompleted(this WebBrowser browser, int timeoutInMilliseconds = 500)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeoutInMilliseconds);
    timeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;
    timeoutTimer.Elapsed += (s,e) => tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    timeoutTimer.Start();

    browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompletedHandler;

    return tcs.Task;

    void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeoutTimer.Stop();
        browser.DocumentCompleted  -= DocumentCompletedHandler;
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```

> Note to ensure the code is thread safe I've gone more defensive here and used `Try...` functions.  This ensures there are no errors setting the result even when edge-case interleaved execution occurs.