# Can I wait for a webbrowser to finish navigating, using a for loop?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
{
  webB.Navigate(URL);
}
```

`webB` is a webBrowser control and `i` is an int.

I want to wait for the browser to finish navigating.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583897/c-sharp-how-to-wait-for-a-webpage-to-finish-loading-before-continuing), however:

- I don't want to use any APIs or addins
- I can't use another `void` function, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583909/1371303)

Is there a way to wait while in a for loop?

Comment: what's bad in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/956020/1714342

Comment: @wudzik the comments claim it's very resource intensive on your CPU while it's going.

Comment: every solution without completed event(best) would be CPU intensive, maybe try using `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: yes, you will be stuck in for loop and you will be doing some stuff (any stuff), it has to affect CPU.

Comment: Minic, you'll want to have a second loop that checks to see if your web control's readystate isn't complete yet, and inside the loop just call `Thread.Sleep(50);` for a 50 millisecond delay between checks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you host `WebBrowser` in a WinFroms application, you can do it in a loop easily and efficiently, using `async/await` pattern. Try this:

```
async Task DoNavigationAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsNavigation = null;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsDocument = null;

    this.WB.Navigated += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (tcsNavigation.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;
        tcsNavigation.SetResult(true);
    };

    this.WB.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (this.WB.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            return;
        if (tcsDocument.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;
        tcsDocument.SetResult(true); 
    };

    for (var i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
    {
        tcsNavigation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        tcsDocument = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        this.WB.Navigate("http://www.example.com?i=" + i.ToString());
        await tcsNavigation.Task;
        Debug.Print("Navigated: {0}", this.WB.Document.Url);
        // navigation completed, but the document may still be loading

        await tcsDocument.Task;
        Debug.Print("Loaded: {0}", this.WB.DocumentText);
        // the document has been fully loaded, you can access DOM here
    }
}
```

Now, it's important to understand that `DoNavigationAsync` executes asynchronously. Here's how you'd call it from `Form_Load` and handle the completion of it:

```
void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = DoNavigationAsync();
    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Navigation done!");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280487/flow-of-webbrowser-navigate-and-invokescript/18283479).

Comment: can you explain what happens with the task when those **if**s in **DocumentCompleted** handler get hit? Does the **DocumentCompleted** handler get fired multiple times?

Comment: @lexeme yes it may get fired multiple times, e.g. for a document with `iframes`. I remember I covered that in more details elsewhere, if interested search for my other answers with `webbrowser-control` tag.

Comment: I tried implementing silent printing at my winforms app. I took your other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734151/print-webbrowser-without-previewing-i-e-single-click-print/19737374#19737374) as a base. Yet I always got web browser in uninitialized readystate. What might be the cause?

Comment: @lexeme, do you mean the sample code from that answer doesn't work for you, as is?

Comment: Noseratio, for some reason, yes, it doesn't work as is. I'm trying to print pdf document, maybe there's something to do with ie security settings idk. WebBrowser stays in the uninitialized ready state.

Comment: I used the whole `DoWorkAsync()` method as is.

Comment: @lexeme, I see, it won't work for PDFs, only for HTML.

Comment: Noseratio, what can I do with pdf? I know I can stick to Adobe Reader (we're using it already) process call.But I thought it would be nicer to do this with WebBrowser in some utility class.

Comment: @lexeme, I have a very limited experience with hosting PDFs inside WebBrowser, but I don't think it's possible to automate PDF printing that way. You might be better off with [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) (I haven't used myself though).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use another `void` function. Simply use a `lambda` like so:

```
webB.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    // your post-load code goes here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use events.
In your loop, how can you know that that the navigation have completed? maybe you are out of the loop but it is only half way through...

Also, looping while waiting is called [Busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and is [CPU expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107593/what-are-trade-offs-for-busy-wait-vs-sleep).

In order to be notified when page is ready, and in the meanwhile keep CPU available for other stuff, use events as @Jashaszun suggested:

```
void YourFunction()
{
  //Do stuff...
  webB.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
  {
      //Code in here will be triggered when navigation is complete and document is ready
  };
  webB.Navigate(URL);
  //Do more stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this while loop inside the for loop.

```
while (webB.ReadyState != tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            {
               Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

This waits until the WebBrowser loads the page completely.

Answer (score 0):

To wait in a thread you can do something like this

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //waits 2 seconds
```

Unfortunately, it is not linked up with the navigation finish time.

Comment: This will block the navigation, which requires the webbrowser control's hosting thread to pump messages in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using tasks like this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++)
{
   Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => webB.Navigate(URL));
   taskA.Wait();
}
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("stackoverflow.com/")

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    ------yourcode------

    End Sub

End Class
```