# A better way to wait for a variable to change state in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, loops, webbrowser-control, wait

I have a loop that goes through a number of values. With every value iterated, a page is loaded in a webbrowser control (with the value passed as a parameter) and when the page is loaded and read, the loop should go to the next value in the list and continue until all values are processed. I need a way to pause the procedure while the website is loading asynchronously and then resume once the page loading/reading process is complete.

The way I am doing is by using something like this, where "ReadingInProgress" is a global variable:

```
      ReadingInProgress = True
      wb.Navigate("http://mywebsite.com/mypage.aspx" & c)

      While ReadingInProgress
        Application.DoEvents()
      End While
```

The "DocumentCompleted" event of the webrowser control set "ReadingInProgress" to false which causes the while loop to exit and resume the procedure. This works, but I realize that it puts a strain on the CPU. Is there a better, less CPU intensive way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of waiting in the loop, why not just move the code that happens after the loop to the DocumentCompleted event handler, instead?

Comment: I cannot do that because code does not happen after the loop, but inside the loop. There is already some code that is executed on DocumentCompleted of the webbrowser. I want the loop to wait until that is executed before moving to the next item in the list. In other words, I need to change the .Navigate command to a synchronous command.

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't call the `Navigate` method from the `DocumentCompleted` event handler.

Comment: I have a list of different parameters that I need to pass to the same page. I use a loop to iterate through each parameter and feed it to the page using the `wb.Navigate` command. I need to stop the loop while waiting for the `DocumentCompleted` to complete before firing another `wb.Navigate` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303758/can-i-wait-for-a-webbrowser-to-finish-navigating-using-a-for-loop). The solution is in C#, but you can use `Async/Await` in VB.NET [in a very similar way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156570.aspx). Using this technique, you would get a natural flow of execution for your code (`DocumentComplete` event is encapsulated as `Task`).

Comment: According to the link you provided, the Await command was added to VS2012. Unfortunately I am using VS2010.

Comment: If you cannot refactor your code to use events and it has to be linear like in your question, at least put `Sleep(200)` after `Application.DoEvents()`. This is still a very bad model. At least, you should disable the UI to mitigate code reentracy.

Comment: @Osprey, does your application have any UI windows? If so, maybe there's a better way to get what you want, using a modal dialog instead of your `Application.DoEvents()` loop.

Comment: Yes, it does have a UI window containing the web browser control. Are you suggesting loading a modal dialog with the webbrowser control in it and then close the dialog from the DocumentComplete event? Didn't think about that and I think it will probably work! Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant :) **-- ops, not exactly**. You could keep your WebBrowser where it is now. You'd create a simple form to use as modal dialog (with a friendly "please wait..." message), show it with `ShowDialog` after calling `Navigate` and close it from your `DocumentComplete` (instead of setting `ReadingInProgress`).

Comment: @Osprey, sorry that's not exactly what I meant, although similar. I just edited my comment above to clarify it. I think it may work the other way around as you proposed - a WB in a dialog - but then you'd create an new instance of WB each time you need to navigate it.

Comment: I used the method you suggested which was even simpler than what I had understood initially. I simply had to add a dummy "please wait" form and load it with show dialog instead of the While loop. Then close it in the `DocumentComplete` event. It works like a charm! :)

Comment: Glad it worked out! I do believe this method is a little more CPU (and user!) fiendly :)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to take whatever is after the loop, and put that in the handler for the  control's `DocumentComplete` event.

Another would be to have this code run in another thread.  It'd start the navigation and then wait on a semaphore, `EventWaitHandle`, or other waitable object that the `DocumentComplete` handler sets.  Something like this:

```
private sem as Semaphore
private withevents wb as WebBrowser

...

sub DoWork()
    for each url as String in urls
        ' You'll almost certainly need to do this, since this isn't the UI thread
        ' anymore.
        wb.invoke(sub() wb.Navigate(url))
        sem.WaitOne()

        ' wb is done

    next
end sub

sub wb_DocumentComplete(sender as obj, args as WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
handles wb.DocumentCompleted
    sem.Release()
end sub

...

dim th as new Thread(addressof me.DoWork)
th.Start()
```

Either way, since you're not taking up the UI thread anymore, you don't have to worry about `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: I am already doing that. The bulk of the operation is done in the DocumentComplete and it does set a semaphore (which the while loop waits for). What I need is a way to pause the original loop (the one that calls wb.navigate multiple times) to wait for the DocumentComplete to actually complete before issuing another web.navigate command. I need to turn wb.navigate into a synchronous command that ends its execution along with the end of the DocumentComplete execution.

Comment: If `DocumentComplete` sets the semaphore, and you're doing this outside of the UI thread, then you already have stuff ready to go.  `for each url in urls : wb.navigate(url) : sem.WaitOne() : (do stuff) : next` .  `sem`, of course, being the semaphore that the `DocumentComplete` handler sets.