# WebBrowser control does not instantiate a document

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` control in my Windows Forms app but it just doesn't load the document.

Here is my code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\Pages\myLocalWebPage.html");
File.WriteAllText(path,webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser1.Document.Encoding));
```

And it gives me a `null reference exception` on the second line. I guess that the Document is not instantiated at all.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access a document **that is not loaded yet**, since you access the `Document` property just after you navigate to the a new Uri, and it's why you get a `NullReferenceException`.

You need to use the [**`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

---

> When does that event get fired ?

From MSDN, the `WebBrowser` control navigates to a **new document** whenever one of the following properties is set or methods is called: Url, DocumentText, DocumentStream, Navigate, GoBack, GoForward, GoHome, GoSearch.

The navigation will trigger the following events **in this order**:

- **`Navigating`** event:

  > *Handle the Navigating event to receive notification **before navigation
  >   begins**. Handling this event lets you cancel navigation if certain
  >   conditions have not been met, for example, when the user has not
  >   completely filled out a form.*
- **`Navigated`** event:

  > *Handle the Navigated event to receive notification when the WebBrowser
  >   control finishes navigation and **has begun loading the document** at
  >   the new location.*
- **`DocumentCompleted`** event:

  > *Handle the DocumentCompleted event to receive notification **when the
  >   new document finishes loading**. When the DocumentCompleted event
  >   occurs, **the new document is fully loaded**, which means **you can access
  >   its contents through the Document**, DocumentText, or DocumentStream
  >   property.*

---

> I have the control invisible.It is not supposed to be used by the
>   user.I am just trying to load a document from the code-behind

The fact the control is not visible shouldn't be a problem. I have tested with a `webbrowser` created at runtime that I have not added to a form (see sample below), and the event is still raised.

---

> How does it get activated?

Here is a *possible* implementation:

```
private WebBrowser wb;

private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (wb == null) {
        wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
    }
    wb.Navigate("YourPath");
}

private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    IO.File.WriteAllText(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Test.html"), wb.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(wb.Document.Encoding));
}
```

See also this thread [Can I wait for a webbrowser to finish navigating, using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303758/can-i-wait-for-a-webbrowser-to-finish-navigating-using-a-for-loop/18305717#18305717)

Comment: When does that event get fired ? How does it get activated?
I have the control invisible.It is not supposed to be used by the user.I am just trying to load a document from the code-behind.

Comment: Correct answer, up-voted. @mathinvalidnik, here's [yet another way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18305717/1768303) to implement `DocumentCompleted` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your local file path needs to be referenced similar to this (the file:// is key):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("file://C:/Pages/myLocalWebPage.html");
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
```