# Print WebBrowser without previewing i.e. single click print

Tags: c#, .net, printing, webbrowser-control

I have a c# .Net application that opens a custom Print Preview form (compromising of a WebBrowser form control that displays a HTML file and a button which prints the contents of the web browser control:

```
webBrowser.Print();
```

However, I now would like to print the HTML file WITHOUT opening this form.

I have tried to load the html into a webbrowser form without displaying the form and called webBrowser.Print() but nothing will print.  It seems I only can print if I show the form and load the HTML into the control.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a sample console app that prints a set HTML files using WinForms `WebBrowser`. You can borrow the `DoWorkAsync` part of it for your printing task in a WinForms application, virtually without any changes:

```
// by Noseratio - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplicationWebBrowser
{
    class Program
    {
        // Entry Point of the console app
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // download each page and dump the content
                var task = MessageLoopWorker.Run(DoWorkAsync,
                    "http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.net", "http://www.example.org");
                task.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("DoWorkAsync completed.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DoWorkAsync failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // navigate WebBrowser to the list of urls in a loop
        static async Task<object> DoWorkAsync(object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start working.");

            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            if (wb.Document == null && wb.ActiveXInstance == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to initialize the underlying WebBrowserActiveX");

            // get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
            // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
            // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
            // and add as a reference to the project
            var wbax = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)wb.ActiveXInstance;

            TaskCompletionSource<bool> loadedTcs = null;
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler documentCompletedHandler = (s, e) =>
                loadedTcs.TrySetResult(true); // turn event into awaitable task

            TaskCompletionSource<bool> printedTcs = null;
            SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler printTemplateTeardownHandler = (p) =>
                printedTcs.TrySetResult(true); // turn event into awaitable task

            // navigate to each URL in the list
            foreach (var url in args)
            {
                loadedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                wb.DocumentCompleted += documentCompletedHandler;
                try
                {
                    wb.Navigate(url.ToString());
                    // await for DocumentCompleted
                    await loadedTcs.Task;
                }
                finally
                {
                    wb.DocumentCompleted -= documentCompletedHandler;
                }

                // the DOM is ready, 
                Console.WriteLine(url.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(wb.Document.Body.OuterHtml);

                // print the document
                printedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                wbax.PrintTemplateTeardown += printTemplateTeardownHandler;
                try
                {
                    wb.Print();
                    // await for PrintTemplateTeardown - the end of printing
                    await printedTcs.Task;
                }
                finally
                {
                    wbax.PrintTemplateTeardown -= printTemplateTeardownHandler;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(url.ToString() + " printed.");
            }

            wb.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("End working.");
            return null;
        }

    }

    // a helper class to start the message loop and execute an asynchronous task
    public static class MessageLoopWorker
    {
        public static async Task<object> Run(Func<object[], Task<object>> worker, params object[] args)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                EventHandler idleHandler = null;

                idleHandler = async (s, e) =>
                {
                    // handle Application.Idle just once
                    Application.Idle -= idleHandler;

                    // return to the message loop
                    await Task.Yield();

                    // and continue asynchronously
                    // propogate the result or exception
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await worker(args);
                        tcs.SetResult(result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        tcs.SetException(ex);
                    }

                    // signal to exit the message loop
                    // Application.Run will exit at this point
                    Application.ExitThread();
                };

                // handle Application.Idle just once
                // to make sure we're inside the message loop
                // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
                Application.Idle += idleHandler;
                Application.Run();
            });

            // set STA model for the new thread
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            // start the thread and await for the task
            thread.Start();
            try
            {
                return await tcs.Task;
            }
            finally
            {
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the DoWorkAsync and printed ok but froze at task.Wait();  Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: I have added a timeout and this seems to work better now (I am working with local html files) but I will keep an eye on this. Thanks

Comment: @Belliez, `task.Wait()` blocks your app UI thread's message pump loop (on the main thread), while a functional message pump is required for `WebBrowser` control. You have two options here: 1) call `DoWorkAsync` asynchronously, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19848530/1768303); 2) call `DoWorkAsync` via `MessageLoopWorker.Run(DoWorkAsync, ...)`, like the above console app does. In the latter case, printing will be happening on a separate thread, so you can block the UI thread with `task.Wait()` until it's done (not a good design decision though - you should keep the UI responsive).

Answer (score 1):

1- WebBrowser viewer right click.
2- Print preview
3- select Toolbox on Page Setup.
4- Check "Print background color and picture".
Happy days

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to render the website as image and then silently print it. Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot) project will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called.

> Silent Printing

Maybe you should search for alternatives depending in your technology. The implementation varies between Forms and WPF.