# How can I get a string in a button_ClickEvent from async method

Tags: c#, async-await

I guys I have the following code:

```
public static CookieContainer cookies;
public static HttpWebRequest GetNewRequest(string targetUrl, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
        request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }
    public async static Task<HttpWebResponse> MakeRequest(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5Accept: */*";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string s = "";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in parameters)
            {
                if (s.Length == 0)
                {
                    s = s + string.Format("{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    s = s + string.Format("&{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
        request.Method = "GET";
        response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
        SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
        while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            response.Close();
            request = GetNewRequest(response.Headers["Location"], SessionCookieContainer);
            response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
            SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I use this functions some method(for example)

```
async Task<string> login(string url, string id, string pw)
    {
       ///code...
    }
```

My problem is: If I want get the result in `buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)` how can I do?

I have tried this but dosen't work:

```
private void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string htmlPage=login(url, id, pw);
}
```

**EDIT**

I' ve solved the problem adding `async` between `private` and void and adding `await` before `login(bla bla)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the following is an obvious solution, it has hidden catches:

```
private async void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string htmlPage = await login(url, id, pw);
}
```

- What if `login` throws an exception? It will go unobserved and most likely will crash the application.
- What if user clicks a button twice, while the previous async login operation is already in progress? You certainly don't want two pending logins.

Here's a slightly improved version:

```
Task<string> _pendingLogin = null;
private async void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_pendingLogin != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login pending...");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        _pendingLogin = login(url, id, pw);
        string htmlPage = await _pendingLogin;
        MessageBox.Show("Logged in: " + htmlPage);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in login: " + ex.Message);
    }

    _pendingLogin = null;
}
```

Comment: I suggest, that you disable a button instead if you need such a behaviour.

Comment: @Isantipov, I only wanted to point at the implications. How the OP is going to solve them, it's up to him.

Comment: sure, just suggesting a better way to do same)

Comment: @Isantipov, disabling a button is certainly good from the UI prospective, but at the same time I'd still keep a check like `_pendingLogin != null` at the beginning of the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Your login method is Async. To put it simple, async methods do not return you a result value when called, instead, async methods return a Task of TResult (Task of string for your login method). A Task is a special type which represents you a promise to calculate the result value. In order to get the result, you should either:

- call .Result property on the Tast object. This *will block* the caller thread till the result is computed. (Very bad for Windows apps hence it makes app unresponsive and even cause deadlocks(depending on a sync method implementation)
- use await keyword to wait asynchronously till the result value is computed. This will keep the caller(UI) thread free to execute other things while your web page is being downloaded. UI thread will get back to processing code after the await statement as soon as the Task is completed (web page is downloaded). This is preferred for windows apps due to this allows the app to stay responsive.

Try this:

```
private async void buttonclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string htmlPage = await login(url, id, pw);
}
```

Comment: };  seems you've been doing too much javascript lately

Comment: @Tinwor , cool! BTW, I've added some explanation just in case smb else traps here from google.