# How to print content of Webrowser in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, printing, webbrowser-control, windows-forms-designer

When I was using windows Forms, there were provisions for **printing the contents of the Webbrowser control--** you could even show **the print and print preview buttons for the end-user--** Is this possible for the `Wpf Webbrowser` and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get to the underlying `WebBrowser` ActiveX Control. [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289217/1768303) it can be done for WPF `WebBrowser`. Then, you call [`IWebBrowser2::ExecWB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to execute `OLECMDID_PRINT` or `OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW` commands. Note, these commands are asynchronous. If you need to track when the printing has completed (spooled), check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/1768303).