# c# WebBrowser Print() Thread in ConsoleApp

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I am exploring the option of Printing a webpage using WebBrowser.Print method in a console application. 
I do want PrintDialog to show up. I have used code from  [WebBrowser Control in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581)
It does give me a good starting point.

My Code looks :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace STAThreadConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            runBrowserThread(url);
        }
        static void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
        {

            var th = new Thread(() => {
                var br = new WebBrowser();
                br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
                br.Navigate(url);
                Application.Run();
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
        }

        static void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var br = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (br.Url == e.Url)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
                br.ShowPrintDialog();
                Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I dont get pop up with "`Application.ExitThread();`" in the browser_DocumentCompleted method. When I comment it out, I do get pop up but thread doesn't exist and my console app continues to run. How to get to exit my application? Any pointers? Thanks all !

Comment: This page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734151/print-webbrowser-without-previewing-i-e-single-click-print/19737374#19737374 has lot of information and should help me achieve printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this post and modified it to suit my requirements. [Print WebBrowser without previewing i.e. single click print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734151/print-webbrowser-without-previewing-i-e-single-click-print/19737374#19737374)
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio