# Webdriver.get() will not navigate to another page until I add wait before the call

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Python 3.5 script that basically logs into a web site (and gets redirected after login) and then navigates to another page where it actually does its job. If I run `webdriver.get()` to this second page right after the login, it doesn't navigate to the target location and stays on the page it gets redirected to after I log in. But if I put a breakpoint or just `time.sleep(5)` - it opens up fine. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298952/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-does-not-navigate-to-another-page) question with the C# code, where it is suggested to add async waits. Is there a Pythonic way to work around it?

My code for reference:

```
# underneath is webdriver.Chrome() wrapped up in some exception handling 
mydriver = get_web_driver()
# do the first get, wait for the form to load, then fill in the form and call form.submit()
login(mydriver, login_page, "username", "password")
# perform the second get() with the same webdriver
open_invite_page(mydriver, group_invite_page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the concept of [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and the `WebDriverWait` class. You just need to choose which of the Expected Conditions to wait for. It sounds like the `title_is` and `title_contains` could work in your case:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


login(mydriver, login_page, "username", "password")

# wait for invite page to be opened
wait = WebDriverWait(mydriver, 10)
wait.until(
    EC.title_is("Invite Page")  # TODO: change to the real page title
)

open_invite_page(mydriver, group_invite_page)
```

Note that there are multiple built-in Expected Conditions. You may, for instance, wait for a specific element to be present, visible or clickable on the invite page. And, you can create [custom Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377437/python-selenium-webdriver-writing-my-own-expected-condition) if you would not find a good fit among the built-in conditions.

Comment: Indeed, merely waiting for the title solved the problem! It still looks weird to me as the Selenium documentation [says](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) _"WebDriver will wait until the page has fully loaded (that is, the onload event has fired) before returning control to your test or script."_  So I thought that would be enough...